# Adobe AIR Captive runtime is large.. anyway to shrink it?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex-mobile

I am working with Adobe AIR and have developed an application which utilizes air and native functionality (Android). The application compiles fine and everything but there is an issue with how big the application is.

Right now the application is about 24.2MB. We've done all we can to shrink it in the Native/Air level but we would still like to shrink it more. I can't seem to find much information on how we can shrink the captive runtime (currently 8+MB) or what other steps we can take to make it even smaller. Could anyone provide some options on what is available to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading,

JoxTraex

Comment: If this is a Mobile app; the runtime only adds about 8MB [if memory serves me].  I don't think there is much you can do to change or fix that.  My mobile game is ~12MB; so part of the size is most likely the data and assets your are including in your app.